# "/assets" prefix disappears causing "No route matches" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stumped by the following error:

```
RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/1/day_schedules")
```

Running Rails routes provides the following:

```bash
$ rails routes
                Prefix  Verb  URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
                  root  GET   /                                               home#index
   asset_day_schedules  GET   /assets/:asset_id/day_schedules(.:format)       day_schedules#index
                        POST  /assets/:asset_id/day_schedules(.:format)       day_schedules#create
new_asset_day_schedule  GET   /assets/:asset_id/day_schedules/new(.:format)   day_schedules#new
     edit_day_schedule  GET   /day_schedules/:id/edit(.:format)               day_schedules#edit
          day_schedule  GET   /day_schedules/:id(.:format)                    day_schedules#show
```

Given this I send my browser to *http://localhost:3000/assets/1/day_schedules*.

The log shows this error:

```bash
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/1/day_schedules")
```

It seems the system is trying to match *GET* `/1/day_schedules` rather than `/assets/:asset_id/day_schedules`

I think the url should match the first route from the rails routes command:

```bash
asset_day_schedules GET    /assets/:asset_id/day_schedules(.:format)
```

Comment: what does the log show for the requested URL?

Comment: Temporarily comment out all unrelated routes in routes.rb... there could be another one that it's trying to match (e.g. starting with /:some_id/)

Answer (score 1):

**3 solutions**
Change your route to something other than `/assets`.
Change `Rails.application.config.assets.prefix`.
<strike>Downgrade to `sprockets v4.1.1`.</strike>
Update to `sprockets v4.2.1`

---

`/assets` path is used by *rails* to route requests to *sprockets*. It's a bit of a hidden route:

```
>> Rails.application.routes.routes.detect {|i| i.ast.to_s =~ /assets/ }.ast.to_s
=> "/assets"

# and it comes before any of your routes
>> Rails.application.routes.routes.take(8).map {|i| i.ast.to_s }
=> ["/rails/mailers(.:format)",
    "/rails/mailers/*path(.:format)",
    "/assets",                             # <=
    "/cable",
    "/rails/info/properties(.:format)",
    "/rails/info/routes(.:format)",
    "/rails/info(.:format)",
    "/assets/:id/day_schedules(.:format)"] # your routes begin
```

So *sprockets* gets to have a go at `/assets/1/day_schedules` request first, which is why I'd change that route name or change assets prefix to avoid this clashing:
*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-assets-prefix*

```rb
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "/shmassets"
```

---

I noticed that `/assets` prefix went away for me too on the exception page when asking for a non-existing file. `sprockets v4.2.0` is to blame, for [downcasing](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/commit/06925180af205000b689345061cfa62faad85ad6) all the headers for *rack v3* compatibility. Guess who didn't downcase the headers yet:

*https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v4.2.0/lib/sprockets/server.rb#L171*

```rb
# asset not found response from sprockets...
[ 404, { "content-type" => "text/plain", "content-length" => "9", "x-cascade" => "pass" }, [ "Not found" ] ]
```

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.4.3/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb#L52*

```rb
# ...is used in rails router
# headers #=> {"content-type"=>"text/plain", "content-length"=>"9", "x-cascade"=>"pass"}
# no match            vvvvvvvvvv ----------------------------------- ^^^^^^^^
if "pass" == headers["X-Cascade"]
  req.script_name     = script_name
  req.path_info       = path_info   # `/assets` prefix is lost
  req.path_parameters = set_params
  next                              # other routes are never used (your routes)
end

return [status, headers, body]      # 404
```

```
#=> ActionController::RoutingError 
#   (No route matches [GET] "/application-244ef50f9c6f7ed789741451c9e3b522197b19fad5288fb64d90eb438d6caac.js")

# except you're asking for "/assets/1/day_schedules" and get
#=> ActionController::RoutingError 
#   (No route matches [GET] "/1/day_schedules")
```

I still prefer the first solution, but downgrading *sprockets* also works:

```rb
# Gemfile

gem "sprockets", "4.1.1"
```

#### Update

Headers issue is fixed in `sprockets v4.2.1`

*https://github.com/rails/sprockets/commit/5d795a7b19877118496ec1d2092d77db21171a4d*

Comment: Thank you so much for this information!  I am considering the first option: "change your route to something other than /assets" .  By this do you mean choose another name for the underlying model which is currently "Asset"?

Comment: @KevinW. you could do that or just change the url path: `resources :assets, path: "the_other_assets"` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources

Comment: I was looking so much for what changed that broke my fallback route for specific missing (intended) assets, and it is this change here. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @TaicoAerts it was a short lived issue, it has been fixed. ^ see update